# SQLAlchemy: using variable table name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to perform SQL statements using SQLAlchemy with a variable table name (come from an external source).
I tried several options but no one was successful.

Attempt 1: With `text()`:

```
def empty_table(table_name,testf):
        with db.connect() as conn:
            s = text("SELECT * FROM $table_name")
            rp = conn.execute(s)
```

receive:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax
>   error at or near "$" LINE 1: SELECT * FROM $table_name

Attempt 2: With `select()`:

```
with db.connect() as conn:
            s = select([table_name]) 
            rp = conn.execute(s)
```

receive:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Textual column expression
>   'my_test_table' should be explicitly declared with
>   text('my_test_table'), or use column('my_test_table') for more
>   specificity

I found in [How to do a sqlalchemy query using a string variable as table name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176006/how-to-do-a-sqlalchemy-query-using-a-string-variable-as-table-name) that it possible to resolve the problem using eval(my_variable) but there is no detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

For a simple `SELECT * FROM ...` query you could just do

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa

# ...

# test data
table_name = 'user_table'

# test code
some_table = sa.Table(table_name, sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
query = some_table.select()
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(query).fetchall()
    print(result)
    # [(1, 'gord', 'gord@example.com'), (2, 'user2', 'user2@example.com')]
```

Comment: Can I truncate a table by this way?

Comment: Re: `TRUNCATE TABLE` - Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028981/2144390)